# dynamodb update list of map

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to save `List<Map<String,AttributeValue>>` into dynamodb

The data looks like

```
"includeData" : [
    {
      "data" : "[VALUE]",
      "work" : "[VALUE]",
      "product" : "[VALUE]",
      "catagory" : "[VALUE]",
      "type" : "[VALUE]"
    },
    {
      "data" : "[VALUE]",
      "work" : "[VALUE]",
      "product" : "[VALUE]",
      "catagory" : "[VALUE]",
      "type" : "[VALUE]"
    }
]
```

In the code, I am creating the update request as

```
Map<String, AttributeValue> annExpressionAttributeValues = new HashMap<>();
annExpressionAttributeValues.put(V_INCLUDE_DATA, new AttributeValue().withL(Arrays.asList([LIST])));

new UpdateItemRequest().withTableName([TABLE_NAME])
    .withKey(keys).withUpdateExpression("SET #includeData = :v_includeData").withExpressionAttributeNames(annExpressionAttributeNames)
           .withExpressionAttributeValues(annExpressionAttributeValues).withReturnValues(ReturnValue.ALL_NEW);
```

I am facing at line `AttributeValue().withL(Arrays.asList(annExpressionAttributeValues)));`

`withL` is not suitable for this requirement. I cannot find any other. How can I update this data structure in dynamodb